# Why does using a method reference instead of a lambda result in a compile error in this case?

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
final var fieldValuesStream = items.stream()
                .map(person -> PersonFieldGetter.getFieldValueAsNumber(functionsParameters.getFieldName(), person)) // Number
                .mapToDouble(number -> number.doubleValue());
```

IDEA highlights "number -> number.doubleValue()" with the message:

> Lambda can be replaced with method reference
>
> Replace Lamda with method reference

But when I change the code to `.mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue)` a compile error happens:

> QueryProcessor.java:31:34
> java: incompatible types: invalid method reference
> method doubleValue in class java.lang.Number cannot be applied to given types
> required: no arguments
> found:    java.lang.Object
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

[Full source code](https://github.com/PJMPR/JAZ_st_2021_gr3/blob/lab03/Mateusz_Budzisz/s24048/dev/lab03/demo/src/main/java/org/example/queries/QueryProcessor.java)
Why is this happening?

[Project to reproduce the problem](https://github.com/ElectroluxV2/repro)

EDIT: Added link to GitHub project with example
project that is failing to build using:

IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-212.5457.46, built on October 12, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.40 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
SDK: Oracle OpenJDK 17.0.1

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Java used to compile: OpenJDK17

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: @MCEmperor I created git repo with all files that Idea needs to be able to open it as project. Entry point is in Main.java. I hope that would help.

Comment: Yep, can reproduce it with your sample project (IntelliJ 2021.2.3, with Temurin JDK 17). Interestingly, IntelliJ itself doesn't show an error here, only when running the build the javac compiler produces that error.

Answer (score 2):

### Not an answer, aiming to provide a simplified reproducible example for other to solve the problem.

```java
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List.of(0.1d).stream().map(aDouble -> {
                    return List.of(1).stream().map(p -> aDouble).mapToDouble(Number::doubleValue);
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Seems the problem is the compiler can't recognize the type of `aDouble` in the nested stream and cause some strange error.

#### Some way to make it compiles

1. Remove return

```java
        Stream.of(0.1d).map(aDouble ->
                List.of(1).stream().map(p -> aDouble).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
        );
```

2. Specify type of `aDouble`

```java
        Stream.of(0.1d).map((Double aDouble) -> {
                    return List.of(1).stream().map(p -> aDouble).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue);
                }
        );
```

3. Not use method reference

```java
        Stream.of(0.1d).map(aDouble -> {
                    return List.of(1).stream().map(p -> aDouble).mapToDouble(d -> d.doubleValue());
                }
        );
```